# Regex for Python with nested results

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I have the following "string":

```
{ see 'identifier' }
     Some Text
     { see 'otherid' }
          Another Piece of Text
     { /see }
{ /see }
```

I would like to "extract" both start/finish in a list, thinking regex of course.
Right now I do:

```
(\{ see([\s\S]+?)\}([\s\S]*?)\{ \/see \})
```

Which results in:

```
Match 1
    1.  { see 'identifier' } Some Text { see 'otherid' } Another Piece of Text { /see }
    2.  'identifier'
    3.  Some Text { see 'otherid' } Another Piece of Text
```

However, I was hoping to capture two matches...

```
 Match 1:
    1.  { see 'identifier' } Some Text { see 'otherid' } Another Piece of Text { /see } { /see }
    2.  'identifier'
    3.  Some Text { see 'otherid' } Another Piece of Text { /see }

And Match 2:
    1.  { see 'otherid' } Another Piece of Text { /see }
    2.  'otherid'
    3.  Another Piece of Text
```

Is this possible in a single regex, or should i be thinking differently about this?

If needed, this is in Py3.4+, no framework or anything but native modules available. Pip installs possible but not preferred. Thanks!

Comment: With regex, you can only achieve that using PyPi `regex` module. With `re`, you can't use recursive patterns. I'd rather use a parser here.

Comment: Good advice, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so when we match end of string, like so:

```
(\{ see([\s\S]+?)\}([\s\S]*?)\{ \/see \}$)
```

Returns the first match as expected, but not a second one.

```
Match 1
1.  { see 'identifier' } Some Text { see 'otherid' } Another Piece of Text { /see } { /see }
2.  'identifier'
3.  Some Text { see 'otherid' } Another Piece of Text { /see }
```

This is still not what I would prefer, but will do the trick if needed.